# Request Layout Improperly Called when using Collapsible Toolbar and Page Adapter

Tags: android, view

I'm getting an endless loop of the following error:

```
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{9968cfe V.ED..... ......ID 64,0-1376,301 #7f0c008a app:id/project_name} during layout: running second layout pass
I/ViewRootImpl: requestLayoutDuringLayout is already in process
I/ViewRootImpl: requestLayoutDuringLayout is already in process
I/ViewRootImpl: requestLayoutDuringLayout is already in process
```

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` which contains a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` within an `AppBarLayout`. Outside of the `AppBarLayout` I have a `ViewPager`. When the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed, the error messages above start endlessly looping.

I have a listener in place for when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is closed so that I can hide and show some views.

```
@Override public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
    if (scrollRange == -1) {
        scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    }

    if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0 && !isShow) {
        view.showToolbarTitle(true);
        isShow = true;
    } else if (isShow) {
        view.showToolbarTitle(false);
        isShow = false;
    }
}
```

When I remove this listener the errors stop. What I'm assuming is happening is that `onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout, int)` is getting constantly called over and over again when the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is collapsed. But that wouldn't make any sense since there aren't any offsets being changed. Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Try stepping into view.showToolbarTitle() and see what's getting called as a result of that method.

Comment: I solved the infinite request layouts by adding 

` else if (isShow && scrollRange + verticalOffset > 0) {   `

But the onOffsetChanged listener still keeps getting called even without me touching the toolbar

Thanks for your help @Karakuri. It was just me calling the same view call over and over again because of the onOffsetChanged Listener

Answer (score 0):

**For kotlin**
If you set any view's value here it will be flooded with `requestLayout` process warning.
You can try with view visibility `gone / visible`.

```
private fun addListener(){
        var isShow = false
        var scrollRange = -1
        tvUserTitle.text = "Hasnine"

        ioCoroutineScope.launch {
            appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { barLayout, verticalOffset ->


                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = barLayout?.totalScrollRange!!
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    //tvTitleHome.title = "Hasnine"
                    //toolbarCollapse.title = "hello world"

                    isShow = true
                    showTitle(isShow)

                } else if (isShow) {
                    //tvTitleHome.title = "" //careful there should a space between double quote otherwise it wont work

                    isShow = false
                    showTitle(isShow)
                }
            })
        }
}

private fun showTitle(show: Boolean){
        if(show){
            tvUserTitle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }else{
            tvUserTitle.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```